# Pass data from view to Bootstrap 5 modal in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, laravel-9

I'm using Bootstrap 5 modal to do CU out of CRUD operations.
I would like to pass data from different models into my Add/Update modal.

So this is how I open my editModal and pass data to it right now:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning edit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editModal{{$category->id}}">
      Edit
   </button>
   @include("manage/categories/editModal")
@endforeach
```

Inside of editModal file:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal{{$category->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <form action="{{ route('manage/categories/edit', ['id' => $category->id]) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="category name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="{{$category->id}}" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="{{$category->name}}">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

and it works all gucci, as long as I'm using only 1 data Model(category)

But there is the case that I need to pass also every Size model item.
That's why I'm returning sizes inside of my index view(in controller):

```
public function index()
    {
        $sizes = Size::get();
        $categories = Category::get();

        return view('/manage/products/index',['categories' => $categories],['sizes' => $sizes]);
    }
```

But for some point, update or add modals still only seee categories model and throws error on sizes loop:

```
@foreach($sizes as $size)
   option value="{{ $size->id }}">{{ $size->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

[image]

What might be solution optimal solution according to my case?

Thanks in advance.

Btw. What do You think about this solution to pass data into modal :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass all parameters to the view as a single array, like this:

```
return view('/manage/products/index',['categories' => $categories, 'sizes' => $sizes]);
```